# ASP.NET Map GIS Control

Tags: asp.net, gis

I need a Map GIS control that I can use on my ASP.NET web pages. Basically the control should be able to read a shape file(which has 3-4 layers). Then it should let you zoom in and out and select certain objects.
Based on the selections, I should be able to do some calculation.
For instance, if I use a certain state, I load the shape file and on the map I should be able to select certain counties only and add up their population.
Please suggest Opensource or commercial controls (<1k$)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/728/15639

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free open source: [SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/)

Commercial. ESRI have a number of options. Their [Silverlight](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/gallery.html) control is free. They have [ASP.Net controls](http://www.esri.com/library/fliers/pdfs/arcgis-for-net-developers.pdf) but I suspect they will be >1K US $